# C language application for data communication

Tags: c, protocols

I am planning to develop an application (could be in **C** or Ada!!) to exchange the data between two computers.
Please help me out to start this work.

Comment: Do you want me to google this for you? help us to help you.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a start if you happen to chose C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Just fill in the "..." part, add new functions etc. as appropriate.

Or maybe ask a more specific question. ;-/

Comment: I too am planning to develop an application - thank you for the code!